# Why the first image is not properly aligned?

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I want to put four images in horizontal line but the first one doesn't aligned like the other threes. My code just for image section is this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/testImages/104055.jpg}
     \caption{Imaginea originala}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/testImages/groundTruth104055.jpg}
     \caption{Imaginea ground-truth}
  \end{subfigure}
  \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/testImages/imageResult104055.jpg} 
     \caption{Rezultatul metodei propuse.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/cannyImage/canny104055.jpg}
     \caption{Rezultatul metodei Canny.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/testImages/163014.jpg}
    \caption{Imaginea originala.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/testImages/groundTruth163014.jpg}
    \caption{Imaginea ground-truth.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/testImages/imageResult163014.jpg} 
      \caption{Rezultatul  metodei propuse.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/cannyImage/canny163014.jpg}
      \caption{Rezultatul metodei Canny.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

The result is:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add the option `[t]` after each `\begin{subfigure}`. This will align the images with their bottom lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
     \caption{Imaginea originala}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
     \caption{Imaginea ground-truth}
  \end{subfigure}
  \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image} 
     \caption{Rezultatul metodei propuse.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
     \caption{Rezultatul metodei Canny.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Captions would look nicer (not as spacy) if they were ragged right.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\usepackage[justification=raggedright]{subcaption}` instead of `\usepackage{subcaption}`.